# Docker for Windows and docker-maven-plugin - "SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection" error

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, docker-maven-plugin

I'm using **Docker Desktop for Windows** v1.13.0 and **docker-maven-plugin** v0.4.13 on my local Windows 10 Pro machine. I'm using `mvn clean package docker:build` to build my project and generate the docker image. The build fails:

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 25.006 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2017-01-19T14:48:45-02:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 68M/619M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default-cli) on project
>   monitoramentoRS: Exception caught:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
>   connection? -> [Help 1]

Creating the docker image on the command line directly (`docker build -t ...`) works fine. The maven plugin was working fine with Docker toolbox and Oracle Virtual Box on Windows 7.

Therefore, I believe there's a TLS-related configuration issue between docker-maven-plugin and the Docker for Windows daemon. I've tried different configuration combinations using `DOCKER_HOST` (no port indication, 2375, 2376), `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`, and `DOCKER_TLS` to no avail. Also tried the `"tls"` and `"tlsverify"` attributes of the "advanced" Docker for Windows daemon configuration.

Has anyone been able to make docker-maven-plugin create a docker image on Docker for Windows?

My `%HOME%\.docker\config.json` file only contains an `auths` collection:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "our-corporate-private-docker-registry-address": {
            "auth": "an-authorization-token"
        },
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "an-authorization-token"
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the docker-maven-plugin config.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.13</version>
    <configuration>
        <useConfigFile>false</useConfigFile> <!-- true yields the same error -->
        <registryUrl>${docker.private.registry}</registryUrl>
        <imageName>${docker.private.registry}/myrepo/myimage</imageName>
        <imageTags>
            <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
        </imageTags>
        <dockerDirectory>${basedir}/docker</dockerDirectory>  <!-- Dockerfile location -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>                                           <include>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 Pro? Could you paste your docker-maven-plugin config and %HOME%\.docker\config.json? I had some problems when using it in Windows 10 also.

Comment: @EricHans: yes, it's Win 10 Pro. I added the plugin config and config.json contents to the question.

Comment: What cloud provider do you have? Did you add the server certificate to docker or login ignoring tls?

Comment: The cloud provider is OpenShift (oc v1.3.0   kubernetes v1.3.0+52492b4).  I didn't add a server certificate, but my docker daemon config has my OpenShift private docker registry listed in the "insecure-registries" collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some configuration element under %HOME%.docker affecting the communication with docker-maven-plugin. Try to remove your %HOME%.docker folder and restart docker. 
After that, run the

> oc login -u user https://url-to-openshift:port --insecure-skip-tls-verify

and

> docker login -u user -p token url-to-private-registry

and then open the %HOME%.docker and if your file is like this:

```
{
   "auths": {
      "url-to-private-registry": {}
   },

   "credsStore": "wincred"    
}
```

then remove the credsStore part because the spotify docker-maven-plugin doesn't support it.

Example:

```
{
   "auths": {
      "url-to-private-registry": {}
   }
}
```

When you run the docker login again, it will generate the token again and you shouldn't have any authentication problem.

After the login, your %HOME%.docker\config.json will look like this:

```
{
   "auths": {
      "url-to-private-registry": {
          "auth:" "token-that-docker-maven-plugin-needs-when-property-useConfigFile-is-true"
      }
   }
}
```

At least, it worked for me.

Comment: Removing %USER%\.docker solved the problem and I was able to build the image with docker-maven-plugin. 
When I added `-DpushImageTag`, indeed I saw an error: "Exception caught: unauthorized: authentication required". 
I removed the "credsStore" element and after the `docker login` command, the "auth" value was automatically filled up, an then `-DpushImageTag` was working.